# Moving DBcontext registration to the data layer (.Net Core Web App)

Tags: asp.net-core, dbcontext

I have a general question of how best to move the DBcontext from the web app to the data layer. The main reason is, I feel it's unnecessary for the Web layer to contain references to Entity Framework and other packages that's only used to DB connections.

What I mean is rather than doing this in the Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Instead have an have a helper in the data layer

```
  public static class RegisterServices
    {
        public static void AddDbLayer(this IServiceCollection services,  string connectionString)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(option =>
                 option.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        }
    }
```

And then in the Program.cs do this.

`builder.Services.AddDbLayer(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"));`

I would really appreciate it, if you have better suggestions or alternative solutions. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there will be any improvements suggested because your "before" was not that terrible and "after" is good enough.

Comment: Don't you think it will make your project become more complex if configure like that? I don't think configure dbcontext in program.cs is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My main reasoning was to separate out the Data layer completely. I thought of a having a factory class to provide a context on request, but thought it would be an overkill.